# I need a Test Case to prove my algorithm/code wrong

Tags: c++, algorithm, testcase

I am making a program which finds the maximum-length subarray whose sum is closest to 0.
Actually i was trying to solve this question: http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/DEVIOUS , but when i submit my code, it gives correct answer to only 50% of test cases.
My code is working fine, and even giving correct answer for my own test cases, so i need a test case to prove my code/algorithm wrong, so that i can find the mistake in my code.

This is my algorithm,

> 1. Create an array 'temp' equal to the size of the input array, initialize all the elements of temp such that, temp[i] = sum of all elements up to input[i]
> 2. Sort the array temp, find 'i' in temp such that temp[i-1] - temp[i] is closest to 0

Here is my code to solve the problem from the link above.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

using namespace std;

struct element{
    int index;
    int value;
};

bool compare(element a, element b){
    return a.value < b.value;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int array [n];
    element elements[n];
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ;i < n; i ++){
        cin >> array[i];
        sum = sum + array[i];
        elements[i].index = i;
        elements[i].value = sum;
    }

    sort(elements,elements+n,compare);

    int diff = INT_MAX;
    int i1 = 0,i2 = 0;
    for(int i = 1;i < n;i ++){
        int temp = elements[i].value - elements[i-1].value;
        if(temp < diff){
            diff = temp;
            i1 = elements[i].index;
            i2 = elements[i-1].index;
        }
        else if(temp == diff){
            if(abs(elements[i].index - elements[i-1].index) > abs(i1-i2)){
                i1 = elements[i].index;
            i2 = elements[i-1].index;
            }
        }
    }

    diff = 0;
    int s,e;
    if(i1 >= i2){
        e = i1, s = i2+1;
    }else{
        s = i1+1, e = i2;
    }

    for(int i = s;i <= e ; i++){
        diff = diff+array[i];
    }
    cout << diff << endl;

    cout << s+1 << " " << e+1;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I found a mistake in my code and edited it, it now gives correct answer for 80% of the inputs

Comment: If you want to find a sub-array, I would think you have to keep the order of the original array, so you should not be sorting it.

Comment: I misread it as well - you do keep the order...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other words, if the profits/losses at the stations are p1, p2, ...,
>   pN the minister would like to handover a sequence i, i+1, ..., j such
>   that the absolute value of pi + pi+1 + ... + pj is minimized. If there
>   is more than one sequence with this minimum absolute value then he
>   would like to hand over the longest one

I think your algorithm is slightly wrong:

> temp[i] = sum of all elements up to input[i]
>   Sort the array temp

The start of the sequence may well be another position than the start of the array - it can be a sub-sequence don't forget.

```
-1 | -2 | 10 | 5 |-10 | 6

   |    |    | x | x  | x
```

edit2: Removed wrong explanation now I looked at the code -

```
if(temp < diff){
        diff = temp;
        i1 = elements[i].index;
        i2 = elements[i-1].index;
    }
```

You do have a preference for -ve numbers (loss). Could it be that the misses are where there is a nearer number to zero because it is either slightly less -ve or +ve (but where the abs value is smaller)?

Comment: While a great answer to some question, this is not the answer to _this_ question!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit :P the first quote if from the link - or have I made a fundimental mistake (Apart from replying to this - ducks for cover)

Comment: I didn't understand your answer properly but your test case proves my code wrong! thanks!

Comment: @A.06 You always effectively take the beginning of the whole sequence as the point to sum from, however you need to create sums for, and compare from various start points and end points to get all the subsequences to get the right answer.

Comment: That is why i find the difference between the temp array elements, because temp[i] will be sum from input[0] to input[i] and temp[j] will be sum of input[0] to input[j], so sum of inputs from input[i+1] to input[j] will be temp[j] - temp[i].

Comment: @A.06 but the sequence in this case isn't position 1 - position 5 which is what your algo would pick, it is position 4 - position 6. Your algo assumes start from pos 0.

Comment: And after the edit my code is giving correct answer to your test case, yet there is something wrong.

Comment: And even if my array begins with 0 it outputs 1+ the actual answer

Comment: @A.06 I didn't look specifically at your code to be honest just the written part so I'm wrong above

Comment: @A.06 - Possibly your comparison is slightly wrong - you choose the lowest (most -ve) number